# Mustard oil test for distinguishing between primary aliphatic and primary aromatic amines?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, amines

Can the mustard oil test be used for distinction between primary aliphatic and primary aromatic amines?

An alkyl isothiocyanate is formed when mustard oil is reacted with a primary aliphatic amine. But does mustard oil give a product with aromatic primary amines so as to make a considerable distinction?

Answer (score 4):

No, aromatic primary amines cannot be distinguished from aliphatic amines using mustard oil test because they both give isothiocyanide and the same byproducts (mercury(II) sulfide and hydrochloric acid).